# Chrome Extension: Can I use php file for html notifications?

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension, notifications

As title, I would like to know, if I can use php file in the **createHTMLNotification**
Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. HTML notifications will only display a page inside your extension, not a page on the open web. Chrome extensions are written using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, which means that PHP isn't an option for rendering the desired notification.